# multilevel dropdown for react recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, ecmascript-6

I am building a multilevel menu and want to use recursion to display the menu. Something like the multi-level dropdown from [here](https://trendmicro-frontend.github.io/react-dropdown/).

In my code my menu looks like this.

```
const menu = [
  {
    name: 'Man Utd',
    menu: [
       {
          name: 'Stadium'
       },
       {
          name: 'About'
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Liverpool',
    menu: [
       {
           name: 'Contact'
       }
    ]
  }
];
```

which I then pass this into my react component.

```
const Dropdown = ({ menu }) => {
    const renderMenu = (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any, index: any) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    {item.menu ? renderMenu() : item.name}
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    return (renderMenu(menu));
}
```

the issue here is that it is causing an infinite loop.

Can anyone advise me as to how I can improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `item.menu` as argument to `renderMenu` when you recursively render the menu.

**Example**

```js
const menu = [
  {
    name: "Man Utd",
    menu: [
      {
        name: "Stadium"
      },
      {
        name: "About"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Liverpool",
    menu: [
      {
        name: "Contact"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Dropdown = ({ menu }) => {
  const renderMenu = items => {
    return items.map((item: any, index: any) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
          {item.name}
          {item.menu ? renderMenu(item.menu) : null}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return <div>{renderMenu(menu)}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Dropdown menu={menu} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. Any idea of the best way to hide the secondary menu. and only show on hover?

Comment: @peterflanagan You're welcome! That complicates it a bit, but you might be able to implement that [purely in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/).

Comment: ah, ok, maybe something easier that I can't figure out. How can I make the secondary menus and any menu below `display: none`? ` - `index > 0` doesn't work as it just does the first menu? Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: @peterflanagan Maybe you could pass down a second argument to `renderMenu` called e.g. `level` that you increment by 1 every time you call it recursively, and you check against that if you should have `diplay:none;` or not.

Comment: I have tried something like this but can't crack it. I have updated my question. If you have a couple of mins could you take a look and see if you can see a solution. If you are too busy no worries :-) Appreciate the help anyway

Comment: @peterflanagan Please don't change the question after it has been answered. Consider creating a new question entirely if you can't figure it out.

Comment: will do makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Your not passing down anything to renderMenu. You should call renderMenu(item.menu)